# Добавление двух и более зависимостей в Gradle

Tags: java, gradle

⚠️ **Вопрос новичка (в Gradle)**

*То, что для Вас само собой разумеющееся, для меня на данный момент может быть отнюдь не очевидно.*

После того, как меня в других вопросах убедили перейти с maven на gradle, то первый же вопрос, который возник - как добавить две и больше зависимостей в проект?

Вот пример из документации:

```
dependencies {
    // The dagger compiler and its transitive dependencies will only be found on annotation processing classpath
    annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.8'

    // And we still need the Dagger library on the compile classpath itself
    implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.8'
}
```

Из этого примера отнюдь неочевидно, как добавить две и больше зависимостей на implementation или другой цикл (или как оно там в grandle называется). Насколько я понимаю, `implementation` - это ключ, а `'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.8'` - это строчное значение. А если зависмостей несколько, то дожен быть массив. Как его присвоить?

### Конкретный пример

Как добавить две зависимости: `org.openjfx.javafx-controls` и `org.openjfx.javafx-fxml`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не нужен массив, нужно всего лишь написать каждую зависимость в отдельной строчке:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.openjfx.javafx-controls'
    implementation 'org.openjfx.javafx-fxml'
}
```

Вот, например, фрагмент Gradle для андроид-проекта:

```
dependencies {
    //android supported libraries
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$supportLibraryVersion"
    implementation "com.android.support:design:$supportLibraryVersion"
    implementation "com.android.support:cardview-v7:$supportLibraryVersion"

    //google play service
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services:$playServiceVersion"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-fitness:$playServiceVersion"

    //other dependencies
}
```

Comment: Благодарю Вас за замечательный ответ с примером!

Answer (score 0):

Все, кажется, проще. Идентификатор - ключ, закавыченная строка  - значение. Вот три зависимости:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.hibernate:hibernate-core:3.6.7.Final'
    api 'com.google.guava:guava:23.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
}
```

Т.е.,

```
implementation -> org.hibernate...,
api -> com.google.guava...,
testImpl... -> junit...
```

Источник примера: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management_for_java_projects.html

Comment: Благодарю Вас за ответ! Прошу прощения, я похоже я не понимаю, зачем вообще нужны идентификаторы. Из тех материалов, что я прочитал, я сделал вывод, что идентификаторы ссылаются на этапы сборки проекта (компиляция, тестирование и т. д.;). Тот пример, что Вы привели, имеет одну зависимость на этап. А если их несколько?